# Ambiguous line through the middle of a box plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am plotting some box plots with the following codes;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [ytick = \empty]
    \addplot+[
boxplot prepared={
      median=77,
      upper quartile=75,
      lower quartile=81,
      upper whisker=84,
      lower whisker=69
    },
    ] coordinates {};
\addplot+[
boxplot prepared={
  median=76,
  upper quartile=95,
  lower quartile=62,
  upper whisker=98,
  lower whisker=62
},
] coordinates {};
\draw[white](69,1) -- (84,1);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The resulting plot has, for some reason, a line through the middle of the second box; Any idea why this line is appearing and how to get rid of it?

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. That is because you mixed the numbers of both quartiles. If you exchange the numbers, everything will be fine again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.